# htaccess redirection conflict

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am writing code in htaccess to add trailing slashes in url, also applying redirection.
My code is-

```
#Add slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 /social-media-consultant http://example.com/seo-consultant/
Redirect 301 /uiux-developers http://example.com/graphics-designer/
```

Now, problem is that when I write code for adding slashes then redirection stops working.

Comment: Change `Redirect` directive to `RedirectMatch`?

Comment: This type of  redirection  "Redirect 301 /uiux-developers http://example.com/graphics-designer/ "  showing me same error 

""The page isn’t redirecting properly ""

Answer (score 0):

1. Change order of your rules
2. Use only `mod_rewrite` based rules.

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^social-media-consultant$ http://example.com/seo-consultant/ [L,NC,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^uiux-developers$ http://example.com/graphics-designer/ [L,NC,NE,R=301]

#Add slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.